# How to Transfer to a different Chat Button w/ Einstein Bots

Tags: liveagent, einstein, chat, snap-ins, bots

I have a chat button on our main website. Right off the bat, the user interacts with our Einstein bot. If they want to talk w/ Support, we want to route the **LiveChatTranscript** record to a different chat button (which is used only on our community site).

Is there a way in Einstein Bots to transfer to a different chat button? I know how to route to a different queue, but the queue I'm trying to transfer to can't receive the chat because they're on the other chat button.